# How to process different type of object returned from php in react native

Tags: php, react-native

I am getting this type of object from PHP. `{"3":4}` Starting array is another value which is encoded into json and echoed. And the rest is another array which is encoded into json and echoed.
How to process this in react native.

`{"3":4}{"1":{"section":"8CSB","lecture_id":"24","subject_name":"MySQL","subject_code":"8CS2","date":"2020-04-29","lecture_no":"1"},"2":{"section":"8CSB","lecture_id":"25","subject_name":"Android","subject_code":"8CS3","date":"2020-04-29","lecture_no":"2"},"3":{"section":"8CSB","lecture_id":"26","subject_name":"Mobile Computing","subject_code":"8CS1","date":"2020-04-29","lecture_no":"3"},"4":{"section":"8CSB","lecture_id":"43","subject_name":"UNPS Lab","subject_code":"8CS5","date":"2020-04-29","lecture_no":"5"},"5":{"section":"8CSB","lecture_id":"45","subject_name":"UNPS Lab","subject_code":"8CS5","date":"2020-04-29","lecture_no":"6"}}`

Answer (score 1):

It's JavaScript at the end of the day and that's JSON - so you just parse it in JS.

```
var Object = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

For a more detailed explanation of what to do, [try this which will go into the picker](https://inducesmile.com/react-native-source-code/how-to-dynamically-load-json-data-to-react-native-picker/).

As for the first part, it's malformed, by the looks of things, so you cannot parse it.

To remove the first part, if it is consistently this, you can do it like so:

```
var Inputobject = <your input>;
var jsonstring = Inputobject.slice(7);
var Object = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

Comment: This is giving an error `Unable to parse JSON string`.
How to get first object in different variable `{"3":4}` and rest of the data in another.

Comment: I have updated my answer to remove the leading 7 chars giving you problems - but if this is not consistent you would need to look at what is creating the JSON output in the first place to remove it. If this answers, please give us a tick, cheers.

Comment: It is changing based on conditions of query. Btw no worries, I solved it by sending two request to API for both part